# Кеширует ли MariaDB частые однотипные запросы INSERT?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

На сервере (Ubuntu, MariaDB, PHP) несколько сайтов. Каждое посещение сайта (пользователем или ботом) фиксируется в таблице для подсчета количестваа посещений с группировкой по часам:

```
CREATE TABLE `visits` (
    `siteID` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `hour` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `cnt` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    UNIQUE INDEX `siteIDdatehour` (`siteID`, `date`, `hour`) USING BTREE,
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

При каждом визите либого сайта в MariaDB отправляется запрос:

```
INSERT INTO `visits` VALUES ($siteID, $date, $hour, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cnt=cnt+1;
```

Вопрос: кеширует ли MariaDB подобные запросы в памяти (с периодическим обновлением данных на диске) или при каждом запросе сбрасывает данные на диск?

Спрашиваю потому, что посещений сайтов достаточно много - сотен миллионов в сутки. Имеет ли смысл использовать memcached для оптимизации производительности или кеширование подобных запросов уже происходит на стороне СУБД?

Возможно имеются какие-то средства, чтобы отследить поведение СУБД на таких запросах...

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-quickly-insert-data-into-mariadb/

Comment: Сто миллионов в сутки, это тысяча с хвостиком в секунду, при равномерной нагрузке. Сотни миллионов и неравномерная нагрузка может означать кратно больше. Я бы больше за транзакции переживал и идентификатор в таком случае. Вам точно это надо в бд ложить? Не проще в файлик писать и потом файлик забирать раз в час, например?

Comment: [Тут](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/poor-performance-on-inserts-mariadb/) пишут про 1250 вставок в секунду после танцев. Но если вам прямо ваш конфиг надо проверять - так вы попробуйте скриптом повставлять и поглядите результат.

Comment: *кеширует ли MariaDB подобные запросы в памяти* Именно запросы - нет. *или при каждом запросе сбрасывает данные на диск* Запрос обновляет данные в кэше таблиц. Изменённые страницы кэша записываются на диск - для этого есть своя очередь на запись. В общем случае сервер старается сбросить изменение на диск в кратчайшие сроки.

Comment: Забыл упомянуть, в конфиге MariaDB я прописал
query_cache_size=0 query_cache_type=0 query_cache_limit=1M
так как по результатам этих изменений производительность СУБД в моем случае существенно возросла. До этого согласно mytop указанные в топике запросы строились в очередь с указанием "wait for que...", а сервер очень часто возвращал ошибку 500. С указанными настройками СУБД кэш таблиц уже не работает?

Comment: "В общем случае сервер старается сбросить изменение на диск в кратчайшие сроки." можно ли управлять этим? - увеличить период сбрасывания на диск?